# My xsl produce two times a single result?

Tags: xml, xslt

My xml is,

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="country1.xsl"?>
<countries>
    <table name="cars">
        <country name="india">
            <var>Rajan</var>
            <pop>90.09</pop>
            <car>Audi</car>
        </country>
        <country name="japan">
            <var>Yenhovong</var>
            <pop>172</pop>
            <car>Sumo</car>
        </country>
    </table>
    <table name="personal">
        <country name="china">
            <var>Leee</var>
            <pop>03988</pop>
            <car>tass</car>
        </country>
        <country name="SriLanka">
            <var>Samarkuma</var>
            <pop>4325</pop>
            <car>sasfd</car>
        </country>
    </table>
</countries>
```

My xsl is,

```
         <?xml version='1.0'?>
         <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL 
                          /Transform">
         <xsl:output method="text"/>
           <xsl:key name = "kkk" match = "country" use = "@name" /> 
         <xsl:template match="countries/table">
                <xsl:apply-templates select = "key('kkk','SriLanka')"/>
          </xsl:template>   

           <xsl:template match="country">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
           </xsl:template>  
         </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here in my xslt, I want retrieve the details of 'SriLanka' country. But the output shows two times the same result. Can you help me how to avoid that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the first template matches on the **table** element, and you have two such **table** elements in your XML to match. It doesn't make a difference at this point that Sri Lanka only appears under one table.

Instead of this statement....

```
<xsl:template match="countries/table">
```

Try matching on countries instead.

```
<xsl:template match="countries">
```